# Identify customer segments based on transactions that they have made in specific period using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

For customer segmentation purpose, I want to analyse, How many transactions did the customer do in prior 10 days & 20 days based on given table of transaction records with date.
[image: Click here to view table / output of below code.]
In this table, the last 2 columns are joined by using the following code.

> ***But I'm not satisfied with this code, please suggest me improvement.***

```
import pandas as pd

df4 = pd.read_excel(path)

# Since A and B two customers are there, two separate dataframe created

df4A = df4[df4['Customer_ID'] == 'A']
df4B = df4[df4['Customer_ID'] == 'B']

from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

txn_prior_10days = []

for i in range(len(df4)):
    
    current_date = df4.iloc[i,2]
    prior_10days_date = current_date - relativedelta(days=10)
    
    if df4.iloc[i,1] == 'A':
        No_of_txn = ((df4A['Transaction_Date'] >= prior_10days_date) & (df4A['Transaction_Date'] < current_date)).sum()
        txn_prior_10days.append(No_of_txn)
    
    elif df4.iloc[i,1] == 'B':
        No_of_txn = ((df4B['Transaction_Date'] >= prior_10days_date) & (df4B['Transaction_Date'] < current_date)).sum()
        txn_prior_10days.append(No_of_txn)

txn_prior_20days = []

for i in range(len(df4)):
    
    current_date = df4.iloc[i,2]
    prior_20days_date = current_date - relativedelta(days=20)
    
    if df4.iloc[i,1] == 'A':
        no_of_txn = ((df4A['Transaction_Date'] >= prior_20days_date) & (df4A['Transaction_Date'] < current_date)).sum()
        txn_prior_20days.append(no_of_txn)
    
    elif df4.iloc[i,1] == 'B':
        no_of_txn = ((df4B['Transaction_Date'] >= prior_20days_date) & (df4B['Transaction_Date'] < current_date)).sum()
        txn_prior_20days.append(no_of_txn) 

df4['txn_prior_10days'] = txn_prior_10days
df4['txn_prior_20days'] = txn_prior_20days
df4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would be very difficult to write if you had
e.g. 10 different *Customer_ID*s.
Fortunately, there is much shorter solution:

1. When you read your file, convert *Transaction_Date* to *datetime*,
   e.g. passing *parse_dates=['Transaction_Date']* to *read_excel*.
2. Define a fuction counting how many dates in group (*gr*) are
   within the range between *tDlt* (Timedelta) and *1 day* before the
   current date (*dd*):

   ```
   def cntPrevTr(dd, gr, tDtl):
       return gr.between(dd - tDtl, dd - pd.Timedelta(1, 'D')).sum()
   ```

   It will be applied twice to each member of the current group
   by *Customer_ID* (actually to *Transaction_Date* column only),
   once with *tDtl == 10 days* and second time with *tDlt == 20 days*.
3. Define a function counting both columns containing the number of previous
   transactions, for the current group of transaction dates:

   ```
   def priorTx(td):
       return pd.DataFrame({
           'tx10' : td.apply(cntPrevTr, args=(td, pd.Timedelta(10, 'D'))),
           'tx20' : td.apply(cntPrevTr, args=(td, pd.Timedelta(20, 'D')))})
   ```
4. Generate the result:

   ```
   df[['txn_prior_10days', 'txn_prior_20days']] = df.groupby('Customer_ID')\
       .Transaction_Date.apply(priorTx)
   ```

   The code above:

   - groups *df* by *Customer_ID*,
   - takes from the current group only *Transaction_Date* column,
   - applies *priorTx* function to it,
   - saves the result in 2 target columns.

The result, for a bit shortened *Transaction_ID*, is:

```
   Transaction_ID Customer_ID Transaction_Date  txn_prior_10days  txn_prior_20days
0          912410           A       2019-01-01                 0                 0   
1          912341           A       2019-01-03                 1                 1   
2          312415           A       2019-01-09                 2                 2   
3          432513           A       2019-01-12                 2                 3   
4          357912           A       2019-01-19                 2                 4   
5          912411           B       2019-01-06                 0                 0   
6          912342           B       2019-01-11                 1                 1   
7          312416           B       2019-01-13                 2                 2   
8          432514           B       2019-01-20                 2                 3   
9          357913           B       2019-01-21                 3                 4
```

You cannot use *rolling* computation, because:

- the rolling window extends **forward** from the current row, but you
  want to count **previous** transactions,
- *rolling* calculations **include** the current row, whereas
  you want to **exclude** it.

This is why I came up with the above solution (just 8 lines of code).

## Details how my solution  works

To see all details, create the test DataFrame the following way:

```
import io

txt = '''
Transaction_ID Customer_ID Transaction_Date
912410         A           2019-01-01
912341         A           2019-01-03
312415         A           2019-01-09
432513         A           2019-01-12
357912         A           2019-01-19
912411         B           2019-01-06
912342         B           2019-01-11
312416         B           2019-01-13
432514         B           2019-01-20
357913         B           2019-01-21'''

df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(txt), skiprows=1,
    widths=[15, 12, 16], parse_dates=[2])
```

Perform *groupby*, but for now retrieve only group with key *'A'*:

```
gr = df.groupby('Customer_ID')
grp = gr.get_group('A')
```

It contains:

```
   Transaction_ID Customer_ID Transaction_Date
0          912410           A       2019-01-01
1          912341           A       2019-01-03
2          312415           A       2019-01-09
3          432513           A       2019-01-12
4          357912           A       2019-01-19
```

Let's start from the most detailed issue, how works *cntPrevTr*.
Retrieve one of dates from *grp*:

```
dd = grp.iloc[2,2]
```

It contains *Timestamp('2019-01-09 00:00:00')*.
To test example invocation of *cntPrevTr* for this date, run:

```
cntPrevTr(dd, grp.Transaction_Date, pd.Timedelta(10, 'D'))
```

i.e. you want to check how many prior transaction performed this customer
before this date, but not earlier than 10 days back.
The result is `2`.

To see how the whole first column is computed, run:

```
td = grp.Transaction_Date
td.apply(cntPrevTr, args=(td, pd.Timedelta(10, 'D')))
```

The result is:

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
Name: Transaction_Date, dtype: int64
```

The left column is the index and the right - values returned
from *cntPrevTr* call for each date.

And the last thing is to show, how the result for the whole group
is generated. Run:

```
priorTx(grp.Transaction_Date)
```

The result (a DataFrame) is:

```
   tx10  tx20
0     0     0
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     2     3
4     2     4
```

The same procedure takes place for all other groups, then
all partial results are concatenated (vertically) and the last
step is to save both columns of the whole DataFrame in
respective columns of *df*.

Comment: Thanks Valdi_BO, for Answer... your code is tiny and tricky.                                                                         since, I do not have working experience in programming, I can't understand, how both of function (cntPrevTr & priorTx) takes input arguments and in which format. 
can you please, explain step by step input arguments of function?

Comment: Thanks Valdi_Bo, for detail solution and idea of groupby. I fully understand your code. and update my old roomy code using loops and groupby. Here is my code...                `def prior_days_trans2(DF, days):
    
    trans_prior_count = []
    
    for group_i in DF.groupby('Customer_ID').Transaction_Date:
        for j in group_i[1]:
            trans = group_i[1].between(j - pd.Timedelta(days=days), j - pd.Timedelta(days=1)).sum()
            trans_prior_count.append(trans)
    
    DF['trans_prior_'+str(days)+'days'] = trans_prior_count
    return DF
prior_days_trans2(df2, 10)`